# What is the best directory for script files?

Tags: bash, scripts, files, directory, command-line

I have my own shell script files and I want to run them in terminal, keeping them in `/usr/bin` folder. But my question is: which directory is best for keeping files of my own script? I want to use this files when I call my script in Terminal. `/opt`, `/usr/local`, e.t.c. Which is the best choise?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$HOME/bin` is probably a good place if you want to call them without directory prefix. That folder is in your path so you can run your scripts like if they were installed in `/usr/bin` for example.

But you can place them wherever you want, to keep your directory structure organised and optionally add those folders to `PATH` aswell.

Comment: yes, I know, my script files are in /usr/bin. I want to know where I must keep my necessary files/folders which my script works on them?

Comment: @ZiyaddinSadigov You can use `~/.config/myfiles` for those files and access them in your script with `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/myfiles`.

Comment: For system-wide scripts I'd recommend `/usr/local/bin` (user) or `/usr/local/sbin` (root only). It would be a pain to link/copy them in all user's home directories.

Comment: @gertvdijk thanks, nice comment! You say that further files I can keep in /usr/local/bin? Script will work with files in /usr/local/bin?

Comment: @ZiyaddinSadigov See your path (execute `echo $PATH`) and you'll see.